# PHP: 3dcart Api Batch Capture

Tags: php, api

I just start to use the 3dcart from shopify, and want a Batch Capture
 function like the [Batch Capture App](https://apps.3dcart.com/batch-payment-capture.html), which is really expensive. I checked the [3dcart api document](https://apirest.3dcart.com/Help/Api/PUT-3dCartWebAPI-v1-Orders-orderid-Transactions-transactionindexid), then tried its api:

> PUT 3dCartWebAPI/v1/Orders/{orderid}/Transactions/{transactionindexid}

my php code like:

```
$update_data = array(
    'TransactionIndexID'=>2,
    'OrderID'=>5,
    'TransactionID'=>41526806930,
    'TransactionType'=>'Capture',
    'TransactionAmount'=>0.01,
    'TransactionCaptured'=>1,
);
$data = json_encode($update_data);

$http_header = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'SecureUrl: {my-secure_url}',
    'PrivateKey: {my-private_key}',
    'Token: {my-token}',
);

// PUT 3dCartWebAPI/v1/Orders/{orderid}/Transactions/{transactionindexid}
$ch = curl_init('https://apirest.3dcart.com/3dCartWebAPI/v1/Orders/5/Transactions/2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array_merge($http_header, array("Content-Length: " . strlen($data))));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($response,true));
```

I got the successful result:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'Key' => string 'TransactionID' (length=13)
        'Value' => string '2' (length=1)
        'Status' => string '200' (length=3)
        'Message' => string 'Updated successfully' (length=20)
  )
)
```

I checked my store admin, the TransactionType was changed to 'Capture' from 'Authorize', but when I checked my bank account, there is no capture item.

how can I submit to 3dcart a correct capture request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed with our developers that capturing via the api is not possible. Once you have the plugin however, just changing the status (even via the API) will capture the payment.